# How to interpret this Uncertainty?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I am unsure of how to interpret the uncertainty given for a Multimeter I have been using. Everything is listed as follows ±(0.8%+10). I have never seen uncertainty listed this way, with a +"x" after the percent uncertainty. What range does this correspond to exactly, -10.8% to 10.8% or is it -0.18% to 0.18%? Here is a link to the datasheet: [Digital Multimeter Datasheet](http://www.smart-prototyping.com/image/data/3_equipment/1_electronic/multimeters/100409%20-%20Victor%20VC830L%20Manual.pdf). Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe it is a relative and absolute error. For example you measure 200 V, then the uncertainty is 0.008×200+10=11.6 V. However that 10 might also be in mV, but it should be specified in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that there are two parts to the error.  One part is proportional to the reading (0.8%), and the other part is a absolute error (10).

For example, if a reading is 174, then there is 174 x 0.8% = 1.4 proportional error, plus the 10 fixed error for a total error of 11.4.  A reading of 174 therefore means the actual value is in the range of 162.6 to 185.4.